# Correcting time disparity on Thunderbird calendar import:

Tags: thunderbird, calendar

Attempting to import an ICS calendar to Thunderbird.

For some reason there is a time disparity, possibly having to do with UTC

Here is an event time, for example:

> DTSTART;TZID=GMT-05:20230927T110000Z
> DTEND;TZID=GMT-05:20230927T140000Z

Event is supposed to start at 11am and end at 2pm east coast time (GMT-05)

After TB imports all the data from ICS into a list of "which of these events (or all) do you wish to place in calendar?", it shows this time information for the event:

> Start Date: Wednesday. September 27. 2023 7:00 AM
> (Wednesday, September 27, 2023 11:00 AM UTC)
> End Date: Wednesday, September 27. 2023 10:00 AM
> (Wednesday, September 27, 2023 2:00 PM UTC)

When it actually imports the event onto the calendar, the start time is 7am and the end time is 10am

What must I do to import times I need, which is the start time of 11am and finish time of 2pm?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your time notation not quite conforms to the iCalendar specs. "GMT-05" conflicts with the trailing "Z".
The "Z" designates UTC time.
Try it without the "Z".

Refer to [iCalendar.org](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-3-5-date-time.html).
There's also an [iCalendar Validator](https://icalendar.org/validator.html) to test your ics-file or text.